# Is there any way to find the cummulative difference in hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table which has two columns, time, errors as below

**#Time****#errors**
00:15:00   100000
00:30:00   100000
00:45:00   100000
01:00:00   100100
01:15:00   100300
01:30:00   100300
01:45:00   100700

I want the cummulative difference between the errors like below

**#Time****#errors****#cummulate_errors**
00:15:00   100000  0
00:30:00   100000  0
00:45:00   100000  100
01:00:00   100100  200
01:15:00   100300  0
01:30:00   100300  400
01:45:00   100700

Anyone suggest doing this using hive windowing function ?

Comment: this doesn't look like a cumulative error, but just the error with respect to the next row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       (lead(errors) over (order by time) - errors) as diff_to_next
from t;
```

As a note:  I would normally phrase this using `lag()`, which is the number of errors since the previous row rather than the next row.  That means that on a given row, the sum of the diffs is equal to the value on that row.